# CSS frosted glass positioned incorrectly

Tags: html, css, blur

I'm trying to achive frosted glass effect with CSS like here: https://codepen.io/GreggOD/full/xLbboZ

But I think, I'm missing something, because it shows me the full image, but smaller size

I have set `background-size: cover; background-attachment: fixed;`, yet this doesn't fix the problem

```css
#second_wrapper {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/2466644/pexels-photo-2466644.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
}

#test_image {
  background: inherit;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#blur {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div id='second_wrapper'>
  <div id='test_image'>
    <div id='blur'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what u wanted?
I added new css rules to `#test_image:after`

```
  background: inherit;
  position: relative;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  /*transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
```

Note that you cannot use `transform` in this case , because, when you transform, the **inherited background image** also **moves** with the div.

*Try uncommenting transform and change the values of translate in devtools*

```css
#second_wrapper {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/2466644/pexels-photo-2466644.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
}

#test_image {
  background: inherit;
  position: relative;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  /*transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}

#test_image:after {
  content: "";
  background: inherit;
  filter: blur(10px);
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id='second_wrapper'>
  <div id='test_image'>
    <div id=''>
      T
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly! Thanks, the problem was with transform, I didn't know about that.
Then, I think, I will do the necessary vertical positionaning with `table-cell`. Thanks a lot!